# A trivial center for a p-group.

Tags: group-theory, p-groups, wreath-product

Can a p-group, where $p$ is a prime, have a trivial center? I'm supposed to consider the restricted wreath product of $C_p \wr T_p$, where $C_p$ is the cyclic group of order $p$ and $T_p$ is the $p$-primary part of the additive group of rationals modulo $1$.

To be honest, I don't understand how a wreath product can be constructed on an infinite group (is $T_p$ infinite? If not, how so?). Furthermore, how do I show the center is trivial?

Comment: A finite $p$-group can't have a trivial center, by the class equation. For infinite groups, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49349/simplest-example-of-an-infinite-p-group-with-trivial-center also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993583/center-of-a-p-group

Comment: The group you are considering is an infinite $p$-group with trivial centre. But if you don't understand the definition, then it is difficult for you to do much!